# Pinterest API pin requests return {"data":null}

Tags: json, pinterest

After sending a certain number of pins automatically (I am not sure how many), I start getting a response

```
{"data":null}
```

There is no error text or response code attached. This is not the same error as I get when I have reached my pin limit, sent an invalid request, etc., and there is nothing in the documentation that explains what this could indicate. And after several days, I was able to send the pins again without getting the response.

I have tried to contact Pinterest directly and got no response. Has anyone else gotten this response and does anyone know what it means?

Comment: Seems like maybe you were marked as a spammer if it started working again a few days later.

Comment: Yup, I found an email confirming it had been marked as a spammer account. Wish the response included that info.